# I Don't know why it showing error when I try to knit R markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio, knitr

When I try to knit my R markdown file, it keeps running this error. I use Mac OS

```
sh: /Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app/quarto/bin/tools/pandoc: Bad CPU type in executable
Error in strsplit(info, "\n")[[1]] : subscript out of bounds
Calls: <Anonymous> ... pandoc_available -> find_pandoc -> lapply -> FUN -> get_pandoc_version
In addition: Warning message:
In system(paste(shQuote(path), "--version"), intern = TRUE) :
  running command ''/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app/quarto/bin/tools/pandoc' --version' had status 126
Execution halted
```

I tried to reopen it and update the version of my rstudio.

Comment: It looks like a few errors. I'd start by reinstalling pandoc and making sure you have the appropriate version for your computer. The error says "Bad CPU type" – are you sure you installed the version compatible with your computer? Does your computer have an Intel Chip or Apple Silicon (M1 or M2)? Make sure you have the right version of pandoc installed.

Comment: You've also got an error where `strsplit(info, "\n")` is returning a vector of length 0 (which is why subscript 1 is out of bounds). That's probably because `info` doesn't have a value, but without seeing your code and data I can't diagnose more. Make sure that `info` is getting the value you expect. You might want to put a `print(info)` statement before this for troubleshooting

Comment: Looks like others have had this problem and it likely relates to a compatibility issue with MacOS. There are some suggestions for workarounds here: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/12512